# Bash - Move files that contain certain string

Tags: bash, grep

I have two folders: `Controls` and `Patients`. Inside each one of these there are several folders for different individuals (`CO1`, `CO2`), with this organization:

```
   Controls

   └───C01
   │   └───ROIS 
   │       └───rs_rois (imgs inside)
   │   └───Cortical_masks
   │       └─── accumbens
   │       └─── putamen
   │       └─── caudatus
   │   
   └───C02
   │   └───ROIS 
   │       └───rs_rois (imgs inside)
   │   └───Cortical_masks
   │       └─── accumbens
   │       └─── putamen
   │       └─── caudatus
```

And the same for `Patients`

I want to move the imgs from `rs_rois` to `Cortical_masks` folder based on a substring of their names. So for example `L_accumbens_rsfmri` file should go to `accumbens` folder and `R_caudate_rsfmri` should go to `caudate` folder.

This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/media/roy"; cd "$DIR/Analysis" || exit
for group in Controls Patients; do
    for case in "$group"/*; do
        for file in $DIR/Analysis/$case/ROIS2/rs_roi/*; do
            if grep -q accumbens "$file"; then
                mv $file $DIR/Analysis/$case/Cortical_masks/accumbens
            elif grep -q putamen "$file"; then
                mv $file $DIR/Analysis/$case/Cortical_masks/putamen
            elif grep -q caudate "$file"; then
                mv $file $DIR/Analysis/$case/Cortical_masks/caudate
            fi
        done;
    done;
done;
```

This script doesn´t do anything, why is that? If I add some `echo` statements, I can see that the `for file` loop goes through all my files, but the code never gets to the `mv` statements.

Comment: `based on their names.` "based" how exactly? Which image should go where exactly? `why is that?` you stated that `rs_roi (imgs inside)` that it's a directory, and you are doing `$DIR/Analysis/$case/ROIS2/rs_roi` in your script. Did you meant to add a glub expression like `/*` on the end?

Comment: @kamil Alright that´s gotta be it, let me check

Comment: That's because `for file in $DIR/Analysis/$case/ROIS2/rs_roi` just returns the directory itself, not the files in contains. Maybe you meant `for file in $DIR/Analysis/$case/ROIS2/rs_roi/*`

Comment: Warning: do the directories `accumbens/`, `putamen/` and `caudate/` already exist in each `rs_roi` dir? If not, make sure you create them, otherwise your files we be renamed that name instead of being moved into that directory. I would add `mkdir -p $DIR/Analysis/$case/Cortical_masks/accumbens` somewhere before the mv to that dir, if you're not sure.

Comment: Thx @joanis. Now it´s not giving any error messages, but neither is moving the files

Comment: Yes @joanis, those files are already created. I wrote the directory organization in the question. I want to move those files from `rs_roi/` to  `cortical_masks/accumbens`

Comment: I suggest you add `echo $file` just after `for file`, and then replace each `mv` by `echo mv`. That might let you see what's going on.

Comment: But I just figured it out: your grep commands look for the string in the contents of the file instead of in the filename. Give me a minute, I should have a solution for you.

Comment: @joanis, It gives me the files name, but nothing about the `mv`: /media/roy/Analysis/Controls/C01/ROIS2/rs_roi/L_accumbens_rsfmri001.nii.gz``

Comment: Try replacing the `grep` by this: `if [[ $file =~ accumbens ]]; then`

Comment: @joanis, that worked! thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `grep` expression you use looks for the string (`accumbens`, etc) in the contents of the file instead of in the name of the file.

Replace each `grep` by a pattern match like `if [[ $file =~ accumbens ]]`...

The script then becomes:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/media/roy"; cd "$DIR/Analysis" || exit
for group in Controls Patients; do
    for case in "$group"/*; do
        for file in $DIR/Analysis/$case/ROIS2/rs_roi/*; do
            if [[ $file =~ accumbens ]]; then
                mv $file $DIR/Analysis/$case/Cortical_masks/accumbens
            elif [[ $file =~ putamen ]]; then
                mv $file $DIR/Analysis/$case/Cortical_masks/putamen
            elif [[ $file =~ caudate ]]; then
                mv $file $DIR/Analysis/$case/Cortical_masks/caudate
            fi
        done;
    done;
done;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/Analysis/
for group in Control Patients; do
  for case in "$group"/*; do
    orig="$group/$case/ROIS/rs_rois"
    dest="$group/$case/Cortica_masks"
    find "$orig" -type f -name '*accumbens*' -exec mv {} "$dest" \;
    find "$orig" -type f -name '*putamen*' -exec mv {} "$dest" \;
    find "$orig" -type f -name '*caudate*' -exec mv {} "$dest" \;
  done
done
```

This is a clear way that doesn't need string comparations.

Answer (score -1):

Would something like this work?

make a file.txt containing the strings you want

`cat file.txt`

`caudate`

`putamen`

Then

`while read p; do mv $p $DIR/Analysis/$case/Cortical_masks/${p} done < file.txt`